# Where are the files from the `Samples` tab in the `LINQPad Tutorial & Reference` folder (see the picture)?

Tags: c#, linqpad

**Question.**
Where are the files from the `Samples` tab in the `LINQPad Tutorial & Reference` folder (see the picture)?

**Description.**
I need files from the `LINQPad Tutorial & Reference` folder.
I searched in the folder `C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\LINQPad\Samples`.
I can't find the folder - `LINQPad Tutorial & Reference`.

I only see the `C# 8.0 in a Nutshell - All Chapters` folder.
I imported this folder later.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inbuilt samples are contained within the application itself, as a zipped embedded resource. You could extract them by enumerating `Util.GetSamples()`: The `Text` property will return the query text, and the `GetRawHeader()` method will return the full XML header. Alternatively, you can extract the zip file from the assembly - you will see it if you evaluate `typeof(Util).Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()`.